# What's the best word or expression to claim that your given example is not fictitious and it's true?

Tags: word-request

What's the best word or expression to claim that your given example is not fictitious and it's true?
In our word quizes we have to write part of speechs, definitions and also give an example for each word. As an example:

> Word Quiz
>   ...
>
> 5. ...
> 6. Profit-sharing bonus (noun) an extra payment made to workers when the company has made a profit
>
> (Here when I want to give an example to illustrate the point, are there any ways to declare that the following *example* is not fictitious and that I didn't make that up?)
>
> e.g. The largest profit-sharing bonus at Ford came for the year 1999, when workers received an average of $8,000.
>
> 7. ...

Answer (score 1):

The example sentence you've given in support of the definition is an **actual attestation**.  You did not make the sentence up yourself. You found it and could cite its source.

Comment: Thanks, now how can we add this "actual attestation" to the example, can I say? "According to an actual attestation, the profit-sharing bonus at Ford..."

Comment: @AmirhoseinRiazi   I think there is no need for such a formality. _According to **the source**, the largest profit-sharing bonus at Ford..._ or _The largest profit-sharing bonus at Ford came for the year 1999, when workers received an average of $8,000.(**the source**)_

Comment: Give the actual source.  *According to a Wall Street Journal article from June 2012, the largest...*

Comment: Thanks & I'd appreciate other suggestions as well.

Comment: @AmirhoseinRiazi: In your original question you asked for a phrase to indicate that a sentence, *presented as evidence of how a word was used*, was not fabricated but something actually found "in the wild", and **attestation**, a term-of-art in lexicography, meets just that need. But now, with **according to**, you're speaking about the sentence as an attestation not in the lexicographical sense. You're citing it as evidence of the Ford bonus itself. That's an entirely different question than the one you first asked.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I'm not looking for a word for distancing myself from the information I'm giving. Otherwise I'm looking for a word to express that I'm absolutely sure that THIS IS REAL & TRUE. So you're right and the usage of according to was wrong. Now am I allowed to ask: how can I add this attestation to my example?(or is it a different question)